# Exception type Type to consider throwing for collection Underflow scenario

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Problem Statement:

I have been building APIs which deals with collections.I have recently came across a scenario where my APIs has to verify the collection Underflow scenario before it does actual operation (to be more precise it operation here I mean will is be Remove/Delete operation) on the collection. If the API found encountering Underflow scenario, it has to throw Exception to the client consuming the API.

What could be the best possible Exception Types that the API can consider throwing for this scenario that make sensor client consuming the API ?

Possible solutions that I could think of are:

1. Throw **ArithmeticException** with a message for e.g "Queue is Empty". The MSDN article [Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228505(v=vs.90).aspx) suggests considering ArithematicException for Underflow scenarion.

   ```
   public T Dequeue()
   {
       if (this.Size == 0)
       {
           throw new ArithmeticException("Queue is empty");
       }

       return this.ExtractTop();
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom exception type **UnderflowException** like OverflowException exist in the C# already.

   ```
   public T Dequeue()
   {
       if (this.Size == 0)
       {
          throw new UnderflowException("Queue is Empty");
       }

       return this.ExtractTop();
   }
   ```

What makes more sense for API consumer is it the solution given in (1) or (2)?

Comment: No, these exceptions were meant for numeric types, a queue is not numeric.  .NET already has a Queue class, just throw the same one it does.  InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I agree that the exception doesn't mean to be for numeric types here in this case.

But, the point is as an API consumer on client side doesn't it make more sense for the user if he/she be able to deal with specific exception type?

As Underflow scenario is very specific, it happens only when no items in the queue and you are trying to dequeue element from it, while InvalidOperationException could possibly happen for many other case ?

Comment: It only ever means one thing with it is raised by Dequeue(), dequeuing an item from an empty queue is not a valid operation.  But hey, do your own thing and document what it means.